# join using a specific field as key

Tags: shell, unix, join, key

I want to find all sections in `section.dat` that correspond to the "Database Engineering" course. To this end, I want to join `result1.dat` with `section.dat` using the course number as the key, only keep the needed fields and save the intermediate result to a file named `result2.dat`.

I have made the `result1.dat`, file but I'm unsure of the Unix command for joining it with the `section.dat` file. I know the lines that I need in the resulting file are lines 4 & 5; the course number that I need to use as key is `cs350`.

`result1.dat`:

```
cs350#Database Engineering#3.0#math229
```

`section.dat`:

```
1#cs110#2010#Spring#MWF#9:00#10:15
2#cs300#2009#Spring#TuTh#11:00#12:15
3#cs305#2009#Fall#MW#11:00#12:15
4#cs350#2009#Spring#TuTh#15:30#16:45
5#cs350#2010#Fall#MWF#15:00#15:50
6#cs440#2008#Fall#TuTh#14:00#15:15
7#math130#2008#Fall#MW#13:00#13:50
8#math229#2009#Spring#MTuWThF#9:00#9:50
9#math329#2010#Spring#MWF#9:00#10:15
```

I believe the command would be something like this:

```
join (unsure of middle information) result1.dat section.dat > result2.dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell `join` a few things:

- Which fields to use for the join (the first one of `result1.dat`, the second one of `section.dat`)
- How the fields are separated (with a `#`)
- Which fields to retain after the join

Here's what the command would look like, with the output:

```
$ join -t '#' -2 2 result1.dat section.dat
cs350#Database Engineering#3.0#math229#4#2009#Spring#TuTh#15:30#16:45
cs350#Database Engineering#3.0#math229#5#2010#Fall#MWF#15:00#15:50
```

`-t '#'` defines the field separator, and `-2 2` tells `join` that the relevant field in the second file is the second one. The default is the first field, so I didn't have to write `-1 1 -2 2` (but I could have).

As you see, this joins the two lines together and removes the join field so it appears only once. You can select which fields should go into the result with the `-o` option; say you want only the first two fields from file one and the 3rd and 4th field from file two, it would be `-o '1.1 1.2 2.3 2.4'`:

```
$ join -t '#' -2 2 -o '1.1 1.2 2.3 2.4' result1.dat section.dat
cs350#Database Engineering#2009#Spring
cs350#Database Engineering#2010#Fall
```

And to get the result into a new file, as you already know, you'd use

```
join -t '#' -2 2 -o '1.1 1.2 2.3 2.4' result1.dat section.dat > result2.dat
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I have spend hours trying to figure this out and your explanation made it a lot simpler!